# Get cart id using javascript

Tags: frontend, requirejs

This question is in relationship with only the frontend. I want to get using javascript

1. Visitor Id : If the customer is not logged in on any page.
2. Customer Details: If the customer is logged in.
3. Cart id : In both the cases if the user is logged in or not. Note that i want the cart id on any page not just the checkout page. So basically i should be able to get notified when an item is changed and i should be able to get its cart id.